# White noise with $Z_t\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$: Do the $Z_t$ have to be independent then?

Tags: probability-theory

Consider $\left\{Z_t\right\}$ with $Z_t\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$, where $\left\{Z_t\right\}$ is supposed to be white noise, i.e. it fulfills the following two conditions:

- $EZ_t=0$  (which is obviously fulfilled) and
- $\text{Cov}(Z_i,Z_j)=\begin{cases}\sigma^2, & i=j\\0, & i\neq j\end{cases}$.

Do we then have to assume that the $Z_t$ are not only identically distributed but also independently? I think yes, since otherwise, we do not necessarily have that
$$
\text{Cov}(Z_i,Z_j)=E(Z_iZ_j)=0\text{ for } i\neq j.
$$

($\text{Cov}(Z_i,Z_i)=E(Z_i^2)=\text{Var}(Z_i)+(EZ_i)^2=\sigma^2$ is fulfilled no matter if $Z_t$ are independently distributed or not and $EZ_t=0$ also.)

Comment: You sort of arrived at the right conclusion with a wrong reasoning. They need to be independent because of the normality assumption you make in the beginning. Independence and zero-correlation are equivalent in a "normal" setting.

Comment: Is this really true? See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normally_distributed_and_uncorrelated_does_not_imply_independent

Comment: If they are jointly distributed, yes.

Comment: How do I know if this is the case?

Comment: It is up to you to impose that or not.

Comment: So I have to write: Let $Z_t\sim N(0,1)$ with $Z_t$ jointly distributed. Then it follows that this is white noise?

Comment: The finite dimensional laws are jointly normal, i.e. Given times $t_1,\dots, t_n$ then the vector $(Z_{t_1},\dots, Z_{t_n})$ is jointly normally distributed. $Z_t$ alone is one-dimensional, so "jointly" does not make sense.

Comment: The white noise property follows from the mean and covariance conditions only. If on top of being a white noise you say that the finite dimensional laws are jointly normal, then not only is it white noise but the sequence itself is IID.

Comment: Sorry, I am confused now. If only know that $Z_t\sim N(0,1)$ how do I know only from this, that it is white noise?

Comment: If $(Z_{t_1},\ldots,Z_{t_n}) \sim N(\mu,\Sigma)$ where $\mu$ is a vector of length $n$ and $\Sigma$ is positive definite then $(Z_{t_1},\ldots,Z_{t_n})$ is jointly normal.

Comment: If you only say $Z_t \sim N(0,1)$ then you obviously don't know if the sequence (or rather time series) $(Z_t)_t$ is white noise.

Comment: This what I mean. But if I say the $Z_t$ are independent, then I have white noise.

Comment: Yes. But starting from $(Z_t)$ being white noise, then you need to also say they are jointly normal to claim that they must be independent.

Comment: And thats exactly my problem. What IS the jointly distribution of $Z_t$ if $Z_t\sim N(0,1)$.